# How to convert params to array

Tags: yii2

I receive the following URL

```
/articles?difficulty=1,2
```

Inside the framework I want to receive an array from that - `[1,2]`. Is there any method in the framework to convert params like that into an array automatically? Can the framework do that? I can do like that `explode(',', $params['difficulty'])` - but I'm wondering whether this can be handled by the framework.

I don't want to pass params like that:

```
/articles?difficulty[]=1&difficulty[]=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no helper in framework `Request` component for converting such values, it can be easily achieved with native PHP `explode` function. Use:

```
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

as you suggested.

But the wrapper of `explode` exists - [\yii\helpers\StringHelper::explode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basestringhelper.html#explode%28%29-detail), it has additional options for trimming and skipping empty elements, you can use it too. But most of the times using regular `explode` should be enough.

Comment: thanks, I was expecting framework to handle that automatically if I used `Yii::$app->request->get('difficulty');`, so I don't forget to use `explode`. Do you think I can implement that myself by overriding `get` method?

Comment: @Maximus I think it doesn't make sense for such small task.

Comment: @arogachev Actually there is a helper :) Check out [StringHelper::explode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basestringhelper.html#explode()-detail)
And it normalizes data in case of something like `defficulty=1, 2,,4`

Answer (score 0):

try this

Use the Request class.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html

`print_r(Yii::$app->request->get());` returns all get variables in an array.  It's like doing `print_r($_GET);` in straight php.

If you want a specific $_GET variable you access it as follows:

```
Yii::$app->request->get('difficulty');
```

In your case it would be:

```
$success = Yii::$app->request->get('success');
$token = Yii::$app->request->get('token');
```

Then after that explode it with comma, so it will get converted into array.

```
$array = explode(',', $success );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't thanks that answers my question. `Yii::$app->request->get('difficulty');` returns `"1,2,3"` instead of `[1,2,3]`

Comment: i think this is the way as you can see @arogachev answer.